# Sending requests from several threads through the same ssl connection

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, ssl, openssl

I have a program that connects to the server with BIO (OpenSSL) and I want to make it with several threads. Should I do a new ssl connection inside every thread or is it possible to send requests from several threads through the common ssl connection?

Comment: what protocol are the requests using?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the BIO library, but in principle, it  is possible to send multiple https requests from several threads through a common https connection.  Two things to keep in mind:  (1) there must be synchronization between the threads, so don't expect major speedups the way you would with parallel computing on multiple threads, and (2) the requests must be within the constraints allowed by HTTP 1.1 or HTTP/2, and you must be talking to a server that supports the relevant protocol.

Comment: @WarrenDew Thanks. I made new connection for every thread)

Answer (score 0):

I made a new connection in every thread. Faster, simpler